# Send UIWebView title to UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uinavigationbar, title

I am trying to send the UIWebView page Title to UINavigationBar.

I would also like it if a user clicks on a link the UINavigationBar shows a back button but if on the home page hide the back button.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

to retrieve the title page into an UIWebView you can use it:

```
myNavigationBar.title = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```

If you want to go back you can do that:

```
if ([myWebView canGoBack]){
    [myWebView goBack];
}
```

To know if the user has loaded a new page you must set the UIWebViewDelegate. For more information see the [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate) and the [UIWebViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidStartLoad:)

Comment: What about Swift?

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS8 you should just use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) and its `title` property.