# UIWebView: Can You Disable Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

You can disable Javascript in both mobile Safari and Cocoa's WebView but I can see no means of doing so in `UIWebView`.

Am I correct?

I ask in relation to this question [regarding obtaining the title of page displayed in an `UIWebView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275876/how-to-get-the-title-of-a-html-page-displayed-in-uiwebview) using Javascript. I had worried that it would fail if Javascript was disabled but it appears the API does not allow the disabling of Javascript.

If Javascript cannot be deactivated `UIWebView`,that renders my previous question moot.

Comment: For iOS 8 and up (Per deleted comment): "There is a way to do this if you are using new WKWebView instead of UIWebView. Which is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34404676/1239426"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no public API to disable Javascript. So it is fairly safe to assume that it won't be disabled.

Answer (score 13):

There is a way!  Using the [Content Security Policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#key-concepts-and-terminology) which is partially supported in iOS 5.1 and up, and a custom header:

```
X-WebKit-CSP: script-src none;
```

You can tell the UIWebKit to not allow javascript on the page entirely.  (or selectively only allow script from a specific domain, more information in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#key-concepts-and-terminology).

To do this from a server you control, you'll have to modify the response headers for the page to include the X-WebKit-CSP header... To do it from pages that are local (plain text or HTML data on device), you'll have to define and register a custom NSURLProtocol for loading your page, and send the header in your crafted NSHTTPURLResponse:

```
NSDictionary *headers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"script-src none",@"X-WebKit-CSP",
                         @"text/html",@"Content-type",
                         encoding,@"Content-encoding",
                         nil];
NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:self.request.URL
                                                         statusCode:200
                                                        HTTPVersion:@"1.1"
                                                       headerFields:headers];
[self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:urlResponse cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly];
```

Comment: Sadly this one doesn't work with iframes. <iframe src="data:text/html,<script>alert(1)</script>">

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov -- If you user your custom NSURLProtocol handler to handle iframes as well -- You'll have to catch all outbound calls (use the delegate callbacks in UIWebView to make sure that it swaps your schema for http or https whenever a URL call is made)

Comment: @BadPirate Could you provide me more codes. I don't understand how prevent XSS when load an html string with `loadHtmlString:baseURL:`. Thanks

Comment: There is a way to do this if you are using new WKWebView instead of UIWebView. Which is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34404676/1239426