# iphone updating webview content

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview

Is there a way to update a WebView instantly without using JavaScript ?
For now I'm using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` with innerHTML and it works perfectly but I'm thinking about (paranoid?) users who deactivate Javascript...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users cannot disable Javascript in UIWebview

Answer (score 0):

Related: [UIWebView: Can You Disable Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302975/uiwebview-can-you-disable-javascript)

Use this: [loadHTMLString:baseURL:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:)

Comment: I'm already using loadHTMLString:baseURL: but if I just want to update a small part of the webview I will have to reload it entirely (correct me if I'm wrong) and I don't want to.

Comment: OK your question did not state that it was only a part of the content that you wanted to update. The related question should provide you with confirmation that users cannot disable JavaScript in your UIWebViews