# IOS: Web view javascript Disable?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I would like to know how to disable javascript for web view in iOS? 
I know this property `javaScriptEnabled`, but not finding any proper way to implement it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIWebView: Can You Disable Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302975/uiwebview-can-you-disable-javascript)

Comment: but there must be some way right,coz for lots of browser on our devices there is functionality for disabling javascript(eg.Safari)

Answer (score 0):

To use that property you will need to use a `WKWebView` instead of a `UIWebView`.  This will limit you to supporting iOS8+.

Once you switch to using the WKWebView all you need to do is set the property on `WKPreferences` to false, and then set the `WKWebViewConfiguration`

In Swift this looks something like this:

```
let prefs = WKPreferences()
prefs.javaScriptEnabled = false

let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.preferences = prefs

let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), configuration: config)
```

Comment: Instead of using WKWebview is there a possibility I use UIWebview only,because I have certain tasks which are there in web view call back method..so I will have to make lot more changes I guess.

Comment: There is no API available for doing this with a UIWebView.  You'll have to swap it to the WKWebView instead I'm afraid or provide a link to another webpage that doesn't have any javascript on there.