# Swift WKWebView disable Javascript

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using `WKWebView` to load some links in my application. I want to disable all the annoying **JavaScript** banners that appear on almost all web pages. Is there a simple function that can do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`WKWebView` has a configuration to disable JavaScript, check the Apple [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKPreferences_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKPreferences/javaScriptEnabled).

```
var javaScriptEnabled: Bool
```

**Update**

```
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false

// Create a configuration for the preferences
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.preferences = preferences

 // Instantiate the web view
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)

// Load page
if let theWebView = webView{
   let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")
   let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
   theWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
   theWebView.navigationDelegate = self
   view.addSubview(theWebView)
}
```

Comment: How can i implement that javaScriptEnabled in my code? i declared a var alpha  = WKPreferences() then alpha.javaScriptEnabled = false but javascript are always loaded

Comment: Have you added the WKNavigationDelegate?

Comment: worked. but now some links are loaded in desktop mode. There's an option to force loading in mobile mode?

Comment: Are the links available in responsive?

Comment: Links are generated by a parser

Answer (score 1):

For us who still use Objective-C, here is the solution:

```
WKPreferences *prefs = [[WKPreferences alloc]init];
prefs.javaScriptEnabled = NO;

// Create a configuration for the preferences
WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]init];
config.preferences = prefs;

// Instantiate the web view
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds] configuration:config];
```