# Webview show device keyboard on touch and ignore website focus script

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am loading an external website using WebView.

The problem I am facing is that the website got some javascript code which focus different input fields on the website. The device keyboard keeps showing whenever you start the application or when the websites reloads (which happens from time to time).

Is there any way to stop/block any javascript xx.focus(); code? Or can you somehow in webview only make the keyboard visible when pressing any input field?

Comment: I know you can disable all the javascript by setting `WebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true/false;` in Android or  set [preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404481/swift-wkwebview-disable-javascript/34404676#34404676) in iOS.  Did not find a way to block the specific javascript code.

Comment: Thanks, the website does seem to require javascript to run correctly tho. So the option here might be to hide the keyboard and see if I can capture user input-field click to show the keyboard?

Comment: You can have a try to disable all the javascript. I did not see the website so I don't know what will happen after doing that. That's depending on how the website is implemented.

Comment: I did try to disable the javascript, but that did seem to cause other problems. Found another solution that works for me, not the best, but it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add/inject a custom javascript to the website.

Not the best solution, but it is working for the website. 
If anyone finds a solution that's better than this, feel free to post it and I'll mark that as a Answer.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // ... //

        // Iniate webview
        WebView web_view = new WebView(this);
        web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
        web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web_view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
        // Create custom WebViewClient to override
        web_view.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewOverride(this));

        web_view.LoadUrl(url);
    }
```

Whenever the page finished loading I'll start with a blur to remove focus from the input fields that could have been added on page load. 
I'll add a click eventlistener, which checks if the clicked element isn't a type of "input". If not a input field - remove focus (the reason for this is that the input field gets focused sometime when you press different buttons).

```
public class WebViewOverride : WebViewClient
{
    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl("javascript:  (function () { " +
            "document.activeElement.blur(); " +
            "var container = document.getElementById('UpdatePanel'); " +
            "container.addEventListener('click', function(e) { " +
            "var input = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase(); " +
            "if (input !== 'input') { document.activeElement.blur();  } " +
            "}); " +
            "})();");
    }
}
```