# iOS UIWebView title doesn't update unless calling this code twice

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, nsurl

Webpage title doesn't update unless I call the method twice

```
NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL URLWithString: webpageURLLabel.text ];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:yourURL];
[webpagePreview loadRequest:request];
webpagePreview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
webpageTitleLabel.text = [webpagePreview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    webpageTitleLabel.text = [webpagePreview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
}
```

The above code fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your request is not finished, so you're too early to call a javascript on that page.
You should make the calling class a delegate of your webview and set the title on `webViewDidFinishLoad:`