# How to get a URL "title" tag value?

Tags: swift, http, get, request, title

I need to get title of page user entered.
URL can be entered as `"http://url.com"` or as `"url.com"`
Also, server can redirect straight request to it (checked on `"google.com"`)

How should I correctly make a request and get a value between `<title>` and `</title>` tags of response?

Comment: Hreno,  can you post some code or give some context here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275876/how-to-get-the-title-of-a-html-page-displayed-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the HTML page your user request.

Try an HTML parser like [Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna)

Once you have installed Kanna via cocoapods, try this code:

```
import Kanna

let html = "<html>...</html>"

if let doc = Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    print(doc.title) // here your title
}
```

To get HTML code from a page, try this request:

```
let myURLString = "http://www.yahoo.com"

if let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString) {
    var error: NSError?
    let myHTMLString = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    if let error = error {
        print("Error : \(error)")
    } else {
        print("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
    }
} else {
    print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't  URL")
}
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: big thanks to you! had some problems with encoding while requesting "google.com" but never the less)

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich you're welcome, try to change the `encoding`