# Adding WKWebview in foreground with ARKit(ARSession) in background

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, arkit

I want to use `WKWebview` in the foreground while `ARKit(ARSession)` is running in the background - So that I use the ARKit data like cam and tracking and pass it to webpage in my `WKWebview`.

I am Apple newbie - So i might be missing something here.

To reiterate - I don't want to `WKWebview` in `ARSCNView` (like here - [Can ARKit display WKWebview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131318/can-arkit-display-wkwebview)) but I want the `ARSCNView` running in background and I run `WKWebview` in the app with a specified URL. But I also want to use the `ARKit` data.