# Xcode 9 : Navigation item title of UIWebView is loaded after WebView is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I’m loading a some URL content in WebView. The **title of navigation item is set to web view title** (refer below code) :

```
extension WebPageView: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_: WKWebView, didFinish _: WKNavigation!) {
        loader?.hide()
        navigationItem.title = webView?.title
    }

    . . .
}
```

However, the issue with this is that **content of web view is loaded thereafter title of navigation item is set (reported as bug).**

Is there any way that *title of navigation item is set and then web view content should be loaded?*

Comment: Did you check that https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059707/4601900

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya : Could you clarify me how this is going to help?

Comment: Does your order need to see the title before the page is loaded?

Comment: @AndrewRomanov : This is reported as bug. So I need to figure out a solution that title will be set first followed by WebView Content or both can set simultaneously.

Comment: You can init String with content of URL and find title there after that you will load the page. Or you can set title "Loading..."   while the page is loading.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov : Post by VinayKrishnan is what I was expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer to your question "Is there any way that title of navigation item is set and then web view content should be loaded?" is No, it seems rather impossible, since the "title" of the webview is retrieved once the web content is loaded completely.
However

```
var title: String? { get }
```

The WKWebView class is key-value observing (KVO) compliant for this property.

You can add observer to webview for key "title" parallel to load request.

```
webView.load(myRequest())
webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "title", options: .new, context: &myContext)
```

For more reference
https://gist.github.com/fahied/698e6f3a09d898b0020d1d4775ffef93

Comment: But use of this throws an warning message : Block Based KVO Violation - Prefer the new block based KVO API with keypaths when using Swift 3.2 or later.

Comment: There is a change in the syntax with swift 3.2, please check this example https://github.com/aguilarpgc/KVO